# What is the law around moth damage to wool carpets?

Tags: united-kingdom, tenant, tenancy-rules

My landlord wants me to pay to replace a carpet because the moths have damage the carpet under my couch over my 2 years of stay.

Is this sort of damage the tenant's fault?

Answer (score 2):

Your tenancy agreement is your first port of call.

If that does not resolve your query, guidance from [Shelter](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/tenancy_deposits/what_can_your_landlord_deduct_from_your_deposit) states that your landlord may use your deposit to cover damage you caused in the property, and they should only charge you a reasonable amount on a ‘like for like’ basis.

It goes on to say that *reasonable* amounts of [wear and tear](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/repairs/damage_to_your_rented_home) do not count as damage, and it depends on the extent, but I would say that 2 years of moth damage falls outside of this definition.